# Bootstrap rows are leaving a weird gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have in my layout a container that has 3 columns and should have many elements.

If all elements have the same height it looks very nice, but if one of them has a different height it will move the entire row instead of just one column.

This is how it looks:
[image: Layout]

This is how it should look:
[image: Expected result]

How can I do that with bootstrap (v3)?

This is my html
[image: html]

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS and HTML alone, using Jquery there is a trick.  I was down this road long back and I know it can be done by jquery.

Comment: Why not? Isn't `float` made exactly for this?

Comment: I know it sounds weird but in bootstrap this is one problem with rows

Comment: Let me know if you are open to solution using jquery

Comment: I am. Your solution works with turbolinks?

Comment: Classic CSS issue. You can only use fixed height in CSS to achieve what you need. If that is not an option you will have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive that, if you don't want to have a fixed height in elements, I think you should follow a column based strategy instead of row based one because your cols do not have an equal height, so when floating the break the flux you actually want.

But if you want it to exactly have it like in your design, I suggest using JavaScript.